# Query on Lambda syntax

Tags: lambda, akka

I am new to Lambda. I have the following queries on the code snippet given below.

1. Who provides the values, reply & failure?
2. I see 2 parameters reply & failure here. Why not 1 or 3? Where do we define set of parameters?
3. Please refer me to any relevant tutorial for further understanding.

   ```
    //Akka code snippet
    CompletionStage<HashResult> results = AskPattern.ask(....);

    results.whenComplete( (reply, failure) ->  {
        if (reply == null) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`AskPattern.ask` results in a `CompletionStage<HashResult>`, which defines the `whenComplete` method to take a `BiConsumer<? super HashResult, ? super Throwable>` as it's argument.

A `BiConsumer` is an operation which accepts two input arguments and returns no result.

`CompletionStage` in this case follows a convention where it will pass exactly one argument as a `null` to the `BiConsumer`: `reply` will be `null` if the ask times out and `failure` will be `null` otherwise.

In effect what is happening is that `AskPattern.ask` returns the `CompletionStage` and in the background sends a message to the targeted `ActorRef`/`RecipientRef` (it's not totally clear if this is Akka Classic or Akka Typed)... if a `HashResult` is received in reply before the timeout, the `CompletionStage` is completed with the `HashResult` which results in that result (and `null` for `failure` being passed to the `BiConsumer`).  If the timeout fires before the `HashResult` reply is received, the `CompletionStage` is failed, which results in the timeout exception being passed to the `BiConsumer` along with a `null` for `reply`.